# hide variations from WooCommerce product page dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I hide specific variations from the WooCommerce Product Page dropdown for variable products?

My goal is to only make the lowest price variation with stock > 0 visible.

I've tried:

```
  $variations[$h]->set_catalog_visibility('hidden');
  $variations[$h]->variation_is_visible(0);
  $variations[$h]->update_meta_data( 'variation_is_visible', 0 );
```

When I  insert:

```
print_r($available_variations);
```

into the variable.php file, the variation_is_visible property for each variation is 1:

```
[variation_is_visible] => 1
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on setting the variation_is_visible property.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use in your code at the end:  `$variations[$h]->save();`

Comment: I was able to hide all but the lowest price in-stock variation with the woocommerce_variation_is_visible filter hook and the woocommerce_variation_set_stock action hook in combination with a custom metadata key.  I'm open to suggestions if there is a better solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The combination of the woocommerce_variation_is_visible filter hook and the woocommerce_variation_set_stock action hook is working to hide all but the lowest price variation from the product page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'rip_out_of_stock_variations_not_visible', 10, 4 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'rip_variation_shared_stock' );

function rip_variations_low_price_visible($product){
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations('objects');

    usort($variations, function($a, $b)
    {
        return ($a->get_price() < $b->get_price()) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    $hlen = count($variations);
 
    $ind = 0;

    for ($h=0; $h<$hlen; $h++) {
    if ($ind == 0 && $variations[$h]->get_stock_quantity()>0) {
        $ind = 1;
        $variations[$h]->update_meta_data( 'hide_variation', 0 );
        $variations[$h]->save();
    }
    else {
        $variations[$h]->update_meta_data( 'hide_variation', 1 );
        $variations[$h]->save();
    }
    }
}

function rip_out_of_stock_variations_not_visible( $is_visible, $variation_id, $parent_id, $variation ) {
    return $variation->get_meta('hide_variation') == 1 ? false : true;
}


function rip_variation_shared_stock( $updated_variation ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $updated_variation->get_parent_id() );
    rip_variations_low_price_visible($product);
}
```